# Increasing y-axis on plot as it appears it naturally truncates part of the plot

Tags: plotting

Changing the x-axis is fine and it will allow me to do so. When I want to change the y-axis (2D vertical), an error occurs. It appears as if the mathematica plot is missing some of the graph data.

Is there a way in which I can increase the limits to which the y-axis run?

Like you add {x, -Pi, Pi} to determine the interval of the x-axis, I have tried similar with replacing x with y or x with the function definition.

Code Example: `Plot[{Sign[x] - f6[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}]`

Comment: Too little details. Post a small self-contained example code for the problem you are getting. Make sure to format it correctly. Also have a look at `PlotRange`.

Comment: `Plot[{Sign[x] - f6[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}]` is incorrect in terms of syntax, you can find this info in documentation center by pressing F1 over `Plot`.

Comment: PlotRange worked, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html) option to the [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html?q=Plot&lang=en) command.

If you end up with a plot that appears truncated on the vertical axis, for example:

```
Plot[E^x Sin[x], {x, -Pi, 3 Pi}]
```

which produces the following plot:

[image]

However, if you use the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html) command, as follows:

```
Plot[E^x Sin[x], {x, -Pi, 3 Pi}, PlotRange -> 10^4]
```

you will generate the following Plot:

[image]